# Integrate with outlook 365 in web application

Tags: .net, web-applications, outlook, office365, office365-apps

Having trouble finding any information on this at all.

Recently saw a web-based CRM system which appeared to have outlook fully intertwined within its system.

The logged in user could see a list of all their sent mail, specifically sent to a user in the CRM, and could also compile emails in what looked just like the outlook client.

Are they pulling this raw data out and then styling it themselves to mimmick the look of outlook, or is there (I'm hopeful) a set of tools to plug this in to a third party web app?

Appreciate any references you could point me to.

Would like something that is compatible with .NET/classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop edition of Outlook doesn't provide anything for that. As for the web applications, you can navigate to the mail web application and host it in an iframe:

> To instantiate Office for the web applications, a host must create an HTML page that contains an iframe element within it that's pointing to a particular [WOPI action URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/discovery#wopi-actions).

Read more about that in the [Building a host page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/hostpage) article.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I've taken a look at WOPI but it looks like this might be specifically for files (such as word, excel, powerpoint). I'm not sure this is applicable to Mail? Could you show me some sort of an example which specifically looks at Mail??

Comment: Looking at the list of applications here: https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery there is no mention of Mail

Comment: I've never really had it accept incoming mail, but boy howdy can asp classic SEND mail ez pz using its built in systems.
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp